# How to parse dynamic child nodes in json using jackson?

Tags: json, regex, parsing, jackson

Using the code below, I'm able to parse child nodes in JSON using Jackson.

```
JsonNode recordNode = records.get(i).path("values").get(j).path("subValues1").path("subValues2").path("subValues3");

for(int k=0; k<recordsDimensions.size()-1;k++){
JsonNode recordNode1 = records.get(i).path("values").get(j).path("subValues1").path("subValues2").path("subValues3").get(k).path("subValues4");
}
```

However, I'd like to parse child nodes in JSON using Jackson and regular expressions or something similar.

**ex:**

```
for(int k=0; k<recordsDimensions.size()-1;k++){
JsonNode recordNode1 = records.get(i).path("values").get(j).path("subValues1").path("subValues2").**path("$.subValues3[?(@.testKey=='testValue')]")**.path("subValues4");
}
```

The problem I'm having is `path("$.subValues3[?(@.testKey=='testValue')]")` is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonPointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) expressions via `at()` method:

```
String value = records.at("/1/values/2/subValues1/subValues2").asString();
```

If you wanted full expression language perhaps there are packages that do that: Jackson project focuses on lower level access via Streaming API, databinding and basic Tree Model.

Comment: JsonPointer is not woring for me. Any other packages or suggestions please